# Compaction total time in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

Is there any way to find exact timing taken by a compaction for particular table or when compaction starts or ends in Cassandra using nodetool or opscenter. Couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you'll find for that is `nodetool compactionstats`.  If the compactions are actively running, you'll be able to see them queued-up, along with a completion percentage and an estimate on the time remaining.

[DataStax docs - nodetool compactionstats](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsCompactionStats.html)

```
pending tasks: 5
                compaction type        keyspace           table       completed           total      unit     progress
                Compaction            Keyspace1       Standard1       282310680       302170540     bytes       93.43%
                Compaction            Keyspace1       Standard1        58457931       307520780     bytes       19.01%
                Active compaction remaining time :   0h00m16s
```